# how to read/write a value from/in the context object cdk step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I am writing in AWS CDK a Step Function which run two tasks in parallel. I would like to access from one of the tasks , a value of the second tasks , which runs in parallel (for example, I would like to know in task 1, which is the time started task 2, or maybe id from task 2).

Here an screenshot of the state machine definition in Step Function.

[image: definition state machine]

In the example of the screenshot, I would like to use the Id of the GlueStartRunJob (1) in GlueStartRunJob.

I was thinking about using the [Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) for that purpose. Nevertheless, I am not sure if this is the right approach...

Comment: Branches in a Parallel state cannot communicate with each other.  Can you execute the jobs serially?

Answer (score 1):

The [Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) is read-only and allows a give state to access contextual information about it's self, not about other states from elsewhere in the workflow.

I'm not 100% clear what you are aiming to accomplish here, but I can see a couple of possible approaches.

First, you might just want to order these Glue Jobs to run sequentially so the output from the first can be used in the second.

Second, if you need the workflow to take action after the Glue Jobs have started but before they have completed, you'd need to take an approach that does not use the `.sync` integration pattern. With this integration pattern, Step Functions puts a synchronous facade over an asynchronous interaction, taking care of the steps to track completion and return you the results. You could instead use the default `RequestResponse` pattern to start the jobs in your parallel state, then do whatever you needed to after. You'd need to then include your own polling logic if you wanted the workflow to wait for completion of the jobs and return data on them or take action on completion. You can see an example of such polling for Glue Crawlers in [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/orchestrating-aws-glue-crawlers-using-aws-step-functions/) (for which you can find [sample code here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-stepfunctions-examples/tree/main/sam/demo-manage-glue-crawlers-with-step-functions)).